# Get releases Github API v3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, github-api

I'm trying to fetch the releases of a public repo in Unity (.NET 3.5) but I keep getting 403 errors:

```
WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data)
```

This is my code:

```
private string GetReleases(string username, string repoName)
{
    const string GITHUB_API = "https://api.github.com/repos/{0}/{1}/releases";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(GITHUB_API, username, repoName));
    string releases = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
    return releases;
}
```

Because the repo is public I believe I don't need to use a token, but just in case I tried adding one and I still got the same error message.

```
webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Token {0}", "myToken"));
```

If I enter from my browser to that url it returns me a json with all the releases of the repo.

Is there a template or something wrong with how I'm trying to get the releases?

Comment: Are you able to make a request to the same URL with your browser and have it succeed?

Comment: @mason yes, [it returns me a json](https://api.github.com/repos/Bullrich/unity-console/releases)

Comment: I tried your code. Got a `System.Net.WebException The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine`.

Comment: After I googled that error, I found that you need to set the user agent of the web client. I did that, and it worked. Keep in mind that servers only deal with HTTP requests and responses. They don't actually know if the client is a browser or a program, so if you shape your request just like a browser would, their server won't know the difference. You can use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the requests and responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following mason's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576074/get-releases-github-api-v3?noredirect=1#comment82110244_47576074), I was able to make it work, now it returns the json!

```
private string GetReleases(string username, string repoName)
    {
        const string GITHUB_API = "https://api.github.com/repos/{0}/{1}/releases";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        // Added user agent
        webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Unity web player");
        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(GITHUB_API, username, repoName));
        string releases = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
        return releases;
    }
```

Comment: A User-Agent is required for all requests - https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required